# How to use SharedPreference to set color to a view?

Tags: java, android, colors, sharedpreferences

Code

```
public class Customise extends AppCompatActivity {

Button mButton;
int mDefaultColor;

SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_customise);

        mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttontextcolorsent);
    mDefaultColor = ContextCompat.getColor(Customise.this,R.color.white);
    mButton.setBackgroundColor(mDefaultColor);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openColorPicker();
        }
    });

}

private void openColorPicker() {
    AmbilWarnaDialog colorPicker = new AmbilWarnaDialog(this, mDefaultColor, new AmbilWarnaDialog.OnAmbilWarnaListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onOk(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog, int color) {

            mDefaultColor = color;
            mButton.setBackgroundColor(mDefaultColor);
            editor.putString("Color", String.valueOf(color));
            editor.commit();
        }
    });
    colorPicker.show();
}
}
```

I have never used shared preference before and there are not many example on how to change color online so im not sure... im using a popular colorpicker library namely AmbilWarna... i have no problem setting the color to the button but i want to save it... like if i exit the activity and start it again the color is back to default... I don't want that.. i want the button to have that previous color which i set... How can i achieve this.. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to read the stored color from SharedPreferences (if it does not exist then it will use as default `ContextCompat.getColor(Customise.this,R.color.white)`):

```
mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
mDefaultColor = mSharedPreferences.getInt("default_color", 
ContextCompat.getColor(Customise.this,R.color.white));
```

and to store user's selection:

```
    editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Customise.this).edit();
    editor.putInt("default_color", color);
    editor.apply();
```

You can change the key value `"default_color"`, but the one you choose will be specific to this color value stored in preferences.